# paint a fiberglass tub

Tags: bathroom, painting, bathtub

We're going to be redoing our bathroom and, unfortunately, there's no room in the budget for a new tub.  Is there a way we could paint the tub and, if so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous DIY epoxy products for refinishing fiberglass tubs. The quality of the resulting finish can vary widely, with best results when properly preparing the existing surface and following the manufacturer's' instructions *exactly* (and using only top quality application tools).

This is one brand (not an endorsement): [Klasskote](http://www.klasskote.com/epoxy_bathtub_paint)

Answer (score 0):

Any finish on a tub has to be designed to be a non-slip surface. I don' t think you just paint a tub. There are special resurfacing preparations for fiberglass tubs that incorporate a non-slip agent.

There are epoxy resurfacing finishes for *lavatories* which make a slippery surface which is totally unacceptable for a tub and are in fact dangerous.

**EDIT**

I once tested a tub in rental apartment where someone had slipped getting into the tub for a shower--resulting in a broken humerus (upper arm bone) and a concussion.

I took a shower in it and it was virtually impossible for me to keep my footing. It was the most slippery surface I had ever been on. I managed to give the surface acceptable wet friction by going over it with with abrasive scrubbing powder barely wet and very firm pressure on a rag.

Before I did that even a rubber suction mat would slide underfoot. I surmised that the tub had been refinished with the wrong product, but I didn't question the management. It's possible this was a new tub that had a protective finish on it that had not been cleaned off, but I think it was finished with an epoxy designed for lavatories.